# Get subfunctions / calltree of a function in Dart

Tags: dart

I have an idea for a new package however I need to inject code into a given function to be able to implement it. Is it possible to get subfunctions of a function variable?

Since the [Flutter DevTools](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/overview) have a similar feature it may be possible on runtime.

The code below shows a basic implementation for a better illustration of the problem.

```
void main() {
  viewCallTree(() {
    print("a");
    print("b");
    print("c");
  });
}

void viewCallTree(Function func) {
  //List<function> callTree = func.getCallTree();
  //converts func to List of sub-functions. Should return [function, function, function]
  //callTree[0](); -> print("a);
}
```

Comment: Not without mirrors, or compile-time build support.

Comment: If this is at all possible (and I'm not sure it is), you would need `dart:mirrors` support, which would immediately make it incompatible with Flutter. That aside, I'm not certain what purpose such a function would serve outside of incredibly specialized code analysis applications that are well outside the 99th percentile of apps and other programs typically written in Dart.

Comment: @Abion47 the purpose would be injecting code after each subfunction call to be able to get the current progress in percent of a function.

Comment: Even mirrors won't let you analyze the body of a function at runtime. It's all compiled code at that point. You need to do source analysis which suggests code generation/preprocessing.